# What is the data being hold in an AudioQueue buffer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audioqueueservices

Can any one tell me what is the data being hold by an AudioQueue buffer in AudioQueue services? Are the samples are amplitudes?

```
Float32 *samples = (Float32*)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
```

I referred the link http://www.davidstarke.com/2015/04/waveforms.html and here mentioned that,The samples hold amplitude values.Is that correct?